# Reading from folder in working directory C++

Tags: c++, directory, fstream

I want to read from a text file which is saved in a folder in my working directory. But unless the text file is in the working directory, it wont open.

Im using a line like this one. what should it be changed to?

```
ifstream myfile ("./folder/example.txt");
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me. Do you wish to open the file irrespective of not being present in the working directory ?

Comment: "./" is usually the directory where the executable is in. Is the "example.txt" really located in "folder"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing) is a good read on those type of things

Comment: Also, you're on unix or windows ?

Comment: Where is is saved when it isn't saved in the working directory?

Comment: Its saved in the folder named "folder" where the exe is saved, im using windows and microsoft visual c++ 2010. And i tried the correct double slash method, but it doesnt work.

Comment: On windows you can't prefix a path with "." (dot), it'll have to be "folder\\example.txt" without the dot and the right type of slashes.

Comment: Actually on windows it doesn't matter what slashes you use (windows accepts both backslashes and slashes, but if you use backslashes remember about escaping in literals).

Comment: Also, please specify what do you mean by "working diretory" - directory your program is, my documents (windows), home (*nix), appdata (windows) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, use this format to open the file.

```
ifstream myfile ("C:\\Book\\file.txt") ;
```

Supposing your file is in Book folder of C Drive.
First write the Directory and then the subsequent folders with double slashes in between till you reach the text file.
Though it is better if you put in your project directory itself, using this.

```
ifstream myfile ("file.txt") ;
```

Comment: i want to access the working directory, like if i move the folder where the program is in to another computer, i wont have to change the code.

Comment: If you dont want to change the code, put it into the project directory. It is also better for portability.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the directory your program is, by simply writing

```
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
```

If example.txt is in the same directory as your program.
Note that this may not work if you can't save in this directory.